# Как выронить блоки в css если они гуляют?

Tags: html, css, css3, html5

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Гуляют блоки, как можно это исправить ?

```
.content_line_news {
    margin-top: 50px;
    display: flex;
    margin-left: 100px;
    margin-right: 100px;

}

.box_line {
    width: 300px;
    margin-left: 20px;

}
.box_line img{
    max-width:100%;
    
}
.box_line a {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Используй `flex || grid`...

Comment: если все изображения имеют одинаковый размер, content_line_news - align-items: flex-end

Answer (score 0):

попробуйте задать всем блокам максимальную высоту

пример:

```
max-height: 60px;
```

Answer (score 0):

в .box_line добавь {display: flex; flex-direction: column;}
в .box_line a {flex-grow: 1;}